# How to handle special characters in DataTable.Select("")?

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm retrieving data from excel and one of the column in excel has '#' like "POLICY #" is the name of the column in excel.

Here is my code

```
string _policyNoColumn = dtFile.Columns[1].ToString();
string _policyNoRow = string.Empty;
foreach (DataRow _rows in dtFile.Rows)
{            
    _policyNoRow = _rows[1].ToString();
    DataRow[] _rowInFile = dtFile.Select(_policyNoColumn + " = '" + _policyNoRow + "'"); //Check on Excel
    if (_rowInFile.Count() == 2)
    {
        _lstInValid.Add(_policyNoRow); //Invalid
    }        
}
```

The value of the _policyNoColumn is "POLICY #". and this what i'm getting.

```
The expression contains invalid date constant '# = 'V0263680''.
```

And Here is the source error

```
Line 501:        {            
Line 502:            _policyNoRow = _rows[1].ToString();
Line 503:            DataRow[] _rowInFile = dtFile.Select(_policyNoColumn + " = '" + _policyNoRow + "'"); //Check on Excel
Line 504:            if (_rowInFile.Count() == 2)
Line 505:            {
```

Highlighted part is `Line 503`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer

Here what i Did

```
string _policyNoColumn = "[" + dtFile.Columns[1].ToString() + "]";
```